# Proving differentiability and finding the matrix D : $DF|_0$

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology, differential-forms

The question: Given a function $F :R^n \to R^m$ such that there exists $c>0$ such that $||F(x)||\leq c||x^2||$, Prove that F is differentiable at $x=0$ and find the matrix $DF|_0$
My try: we know that $$0\leq ||F'(x)||\leq 2c||x||$$
so $$\lim \limits _{h \to 0} \frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h} \leq 2c||0|| = 0$$
and because $$0\leq||F(0)||\leq c||0||=0 => ||F(0)||=0 , ||F(h)||\leq c||h^2||=ch^2 $$ and same for $||F'(x)|| = 0$
so $$\lim \limits _{h \to 0} \frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h} \leq \lim \limits _{h \to 0} \frac{ch^2}{h} = \lim \limits _{h \to 0} ch = 0$$ so that proves that F is indeed differentiable. But I'm not sure what the D matrix is supposed to be. Is my answer so far is okay? How do I proceed?

Comment: First, you mean $\|x\|^2$. $\|x^2\|$ has no meaning. Second, if $f(x)\le g(x)$, you cannot conclude that $f'(x)\le g'(x)$ (draw some pictures of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ like in beginning calculus). Third, you need the derivative as a linear transformation with the appropriate definition of differentiable. You cannot use the beginning calculus definitions.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah but if $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for every x the you can say that $f'(x)\leq g'(x)$,no?